# Chrome not upgrading, netflix not working

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, dependencies, netflix

The following packages have unmet dependencies: google-chrome-stable : Depends: libnss3 (>= 2:3.22) but 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

This is the error I am getting when I try to install chrome. Netflix isn't working, facebook is slow too. Please help me out.

Comment: In the title you say upgrading, in the text you say installing. Which is it?

Comment: Im sorry, the upgrade is not installing. I tried to remove chrome and install it again last night after posting this question. NOW m problem is that chrome is not installing from the software center.

Comment: when i try to install it from the software center, it asks me to repair broken packages and that doesnt work. There are many updates i need to complete from software update center, but those are not downloading either. Im lost.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. Go to the URL and download the libnss3 file
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libnss3/download
2. Click on the downloaded file, Ubuntu Software Center will open a dialog to repair. Click OK and authenticate yourself.

   **Note**: It will update the 'libnss3' library to latest version
3. Download latest Chrome from https://www.google.com/chrome/
4. Repeat step 2 and latest Google Chrome will be installed on your system.

Believe me it has speed up my browsing experience.